# spinner que active cronómetro android

Tags: android, spinner, botón

Necesito crear 2 spinner y un botón de inicio/parada con la idea de que cuando seleccione algo de la lista y de a iniciar se vea un cronómetro para saber cuanto tiempo se ha realizado la actividad física y, ¿se podría hacer de forma que si se cambia de actividad, se guarde el registro y se detenga el cronómetro de forma automática sin presionar el botón de parada?

Para contextualizar las opciones del spinner 1 serían (Abdominales, piernas, pecho), spinner 2 (espalda, carrera en el lugar, saltos).

He probado con agregar el cronómetro y el botón por si solo, pero vincular eso a un spinner escapa a mis conocimientos, ahora guardar los registros y subirlos a una base de datos, menos aun.

muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor añade el código que tienes

Answer (score 0):

Este código inicia y detiene el cronometro

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Chronometer myChronometer;
private Button start, restart, changeFormat, restartFormat;
private boolean isRunning;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.myChronometer);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartButton);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!isRunning) {
                myChronometer.start();
                start.setText("Stop");
                isRunning = true;
            }else{
                myChronometer.stop();
                start.setText("Start");
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
    });
    restart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
    });
    myChronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                    if( chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("00:12")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "time reached 00:12", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //myChronometer.stop();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}